# Java: How to kill Server thread so that running the Server again will not cause "Address already in use"

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I wrote a Server and a Client with GUI to transfer text between them and they work well. I searched Google "how to send files through a network" then I found [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/509758/sockets/java/Send-file-network) beautiful solution (see Andrey Kozhanov reply) . I moved the server class in the link to my server package and the client class in the link to my client package to try and they work well. Now I can send instant text messages, and instant files.

I wrote every thing necessary to make communication work smoothly to meet users expectations.

**The problem is** The problem occur at a specific scenario.

The two servers have different port numbers; (mine for text and the one in the link for files)
**Stage 1**
1- the client request the server to send a file.
2- the server reply with (**Yes**) (*dialogue yes-no-options*).
3- the client navigate the File Chooser's List.
4- the client cancel the File Chooser (didn't send a file).
5- the server informed about the client cancellation.
**Stage 2**
- **again**
1- the client request the server to send a file.
2- the server reply with (**Yes**).  **error** occur at the server side;

the first line of the error is:

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

I begin the receiving thread at the Server package like this

```
        recieverThread = new Recieving();
        recieverThread.setDaemon(true);
        recieverThread.start();
```

The problem traced back to **stage 1** number 5 (5- the server informed about the client cancellation.). since the server thread for receiving files from client start, then at point 5 I must stop it. to stop this thread I use combination of

```
        recieverThread.interrupt();
        recieverThread = null;
```

But when it started again at **stage 2**, it seems that it still running and is not stopped. I want to kill it so that when I want to start a new thread no error occur.

Comment: you should add more details about how do you accept the client request?

Comment: @CuriousMind Why? There's only one way to 'accept a client request', and it has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a threading problem, but a server socket problem. Reusing a Socket immediately is disallowed by TCP/IP because the reuser could see packets targeted at the old user.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516030/java-server-socket-doesnt-reuse-address) on how to reuse sockets.

Comment: Thank you. The link you posted contains the solution to my problem. so I hope you accept my addendum to your answer to set it as my accepted answer.

Comment: @SalehFeek Your addendum was already rejected by the time I wanted to review. But you should consider writing that in an answer of your own.

Comment: I am sorry. I am not good at netiquette. I got that that was wrong. Thank you.